# Strange bug in ggplot2 with facet_grid and large datasets

Tags: ggplot2

Here is a basic example that should definitively work

```
library(ggplot2)

M <- 1e6
df <- data.frame(x = runif(M), y=runif(M),
                 f1 = paste0(sample(c(1,4,5), M, replace = T)),
                 f2 = paste0(sample(c("F2A", "F2B"), M, replace = T)))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_grid(f1~f2)
gg # okay
gg # now not okay (sometimes)
```

However, I (sometimes) get the error

```
Error in `scale_apply()`:
! `scale_id` must not contain any "NA"
```

when `M` is large, as in the example.

Using the debugger in RStudio with `debug(ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot)`, I eventually found something that could be the cause. To see it:

1. run `debug(ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot)` and then `gg`
2. move inside `data <- layout$setup(data, plot$data, plot$plot_env)` and then `setup(...)`
3. move inside `lapply(data[-1], self$facet$map_data, layout = self$layout, params = self$facet_params)` and then `.Internal` and `map`
4. move inside `join_keys(facet_vals, layout, by = vars)`
5. move inside `keys <- id(joint, drop = TRUE)`

Then , in there, you eventually hit the blocks

```
if (n > 2^31) {
  char_id <- inject(paste(!!!ids, sep = "\r"))
  res <- match(char_id, unique0(char_id))
}
else {
  combs <- c(1, cumprod(ndistinct[-p]))
  mat <- inject(cbind(!!!ids))
  res <- c((mat - 1L) %*% combs + 1L)
}
```

The first part of the if else would work fine (were it to be chosen), but in the second (which is the chosen one), we get something weird happening. Specifically, the expression `c((mat - 1L) %*% combs + 1L)` returns a value that varies from time to time when you call it. Sometimes it's fine, but sometimes it returns stuff outside the allowed range (number of facets). This seems extremely strange to me, as the value of `mat` and `combs` stay fixed... Not sure what else I can do.

Can someone explain that? Recall that this seems to happen only when `M` is very large... Thanks in advance.

Comment: ggplot2 version 3.4.3